# How to use Timer

Tags: java, timer

I have an application made in Netbeans and I don't have any idea how to use a `Timer` in Java. In Winform there's a control box of `Timer` which is drag and use only. Now I want to use a timer for 1 seconds after `about.setIcon(about4);` (which is GIF) is executed.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;    
 int  a2 = 0, a3 = 1, a4 = 2;

 ImageIcon about2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/2What-is-the-Game.gif")); 
  about2.getImage().flush();
  ImageIcon about3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/3How-to-play.gif")); 
  about3.getImage().flush();
  ImageIcon about4 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/4About-end.gif")); 
  about4.getImage().flush();
  if(a2 == 0)
  {
      a2=1;
      a3=1;
  about.setIcon(about2);
  }
  else if (a3 == 1)
  {
      a3=0;
      a4=1;

      about.setIcon(about3);
  }
  else if (a4 == 1)
  {
      a4=0;
      a2=0;
      about.setIcon(about4);

  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you're using this in conjunction with Swing components, you better use the java Swing timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, we have several ways of Timer implementation or rather its uses, a few of them are-

- To set up a specific amount of delay until a task is executed.
- To find the time difference between two specific events.

[**Timer**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class provides facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.

```
 public class JavaReminder {
    Timer timer;

    public JavaReminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();  //At this line a new Thread will be created
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000); //delay in milliseconds
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("ReminderTask is completed by Java timer");
            timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit
            //System.exit(0); //Stops the AWT thread (and everything else)
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Java timer is about to start");
        JavaReminder reminderBeep = new JavaReminder(5);
        System.out.println("Remindertask is scheduled with Java timer.");
    }
}
```

Read more from here:

- http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/02/what-is-timer-and-timertask-in-java-example-tutorial.html
- http://www.javatutorialhub.com/timers-java

Answer (score 0):

Declare an instance of `java.util.Timer` in your code (in the constructor?) and configure/control it with the methods found in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
...
private Timer t;
public class MyClass()
{
    t=new Timer(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
           //Code to run when timer ticks.
        }
    },1000);//Run in 1000ms
}
```

Comment: can you just put the syntax on it? sorry for being fruitless

Comment: Something like that should work, the docs show all the possible parameter configs if you want it to run at set date etc

Comment: is that code says. it will execute what ever code i put on run(). after 1sec or before 1sec?

Comment: @Miki how can it run before 1 second?

Comment: before 1 second? you can set the time for it to tick with a date object, or the number of milliseconds from when it is created. A millisecond is 1/1000th of a second.